# "pyOptSparse Error: There was an error importing the compiled IPOPT module" when following documentation

Tags: python-3.x, openmdao, ipopt

I am trying to install the IPOPT algorithm using the pyOptSparse package. I got the SNOPT and SLSQP algorithms working. For the IPOPT algorithm, the build is successful, however when using the algorithm i get the error:

```
 pyOptSparse Error: There was an error importing the compiled IPOPT module
```

I am building the project in a Ubuntu based Docker container, and have followed the documentation(doc/optimizers/pyipopt.rst) on IPOPT in pyOptSparse pretty much exactly. The complete [dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/arntlima/c788c422a640e4a61ef86846e8275239) is available( I have included my attempts using both the apt-based package, and some copying of the source per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38719306)). The most relevant part is:

```
RUN wget http://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.11.7.tgz && \
    gunzip Ipopt-3.11.7.tgz && \
    tar -xvf Ipopt-3.11.7.tar && \
    rm -rf Ipopt-3.11.7.tar && \
    mv Ipopt-3.11.7 /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/Ipopt && \
    wget -P /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/Ipopt/ThirdParty/HSLold/ \
        https://bitbucket.org/mdolab/pyoptsparse/downloads/ma27ad.f && \
    cd /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/Ipopt/ThirdParty/Blas/ && \
    ./get.Blas && \
    cd /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/Ipopt/ThirdParty/Lapack/ && \
    ./get.Lapack && \
    cd /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/Ipopt && \
    ./configure --disable-linear-solver-loader && \
    make install

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/Ipopt/lib
RUN cd pyoptsparse && \
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

In the output of the build, pyOptSparse picks up IPOPT ["building 'pyoptsparse.pyIPOPT.pyipoptcore' extension"](https://gist.github.com/arntlima/74ee5a58cada68bc5f9d2778d0724925#file-ipopt_build_output-L4600).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might get the IPOPT algorithm installed, or how I might debug the installation?

Thanks!

**Additional notes:**

- I did not get the SLSQP algorithm latest commit of pyOptSparse to work, thus I am using the commit fd33788 from late last year.
- I have tried various combinations of the --prefix=/usr/local, but if any one have any specific suggestions on the location and environment variables, I am all ears

Answer (score 0):

### Cause

pyIPOPT, in pyOptSparse, does not currently support Python3. Specifically it uses calls to `Py_FindMethod` and a number conversion call in `/pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/src/`.

### Solution

The [original pyIPOPT code](https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt) has been updated with Python3 support and can be used:

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/xuy/pyipopt.git && \
    mv /pyipopt/src/pyipoptcoremodule.c /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/src/pyipoptcoremodule.c && \
    mv /pyipopt/src/hook.h /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/src/hook.h && \
    mv /pyipopt/src/callback.c /pyoptsparse/pyoptsparse/pyIPOPT/src/callback.c
```

At this point IPOPT runs, but exits without calling the objective. This is because of an status code -12, indicating invalid options. Editing the default options to `def_opts = {}` solves this, and the algorithm is able to converge the OpenMDAO Paraboloid example.

### Further Work

- Update the pyOptSparse version of pyIPOPT with the updated version of pyIPOPT
- Possibly figure out why the default parameters in the pyOptSparse version of pyIPOPT does not work. Convert the defaults to something that works